# How to use ImageDrawableLeft tag of XML attri. Programatically

Tags: android, android-button

How to use ImageDrawableLeft tag of XML attribute programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example, if you are using it on EditText then do it as follow:

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_image);
d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicHeight(), d.getIntrinsicWidth());
//setting icon at left
yourEditText.setCompoundDrawables(d, null, null, null);
```

Comment: i am using the attri in Button.Text Over it and image on the Left.

Comment: yes, it should apply on buttons too. call your button's setCompoundDrawables method to set the icon

Comment: yeah .it's working.. thnx a lot.. I am wondering if i can make the image shift to Top Right corner of Button using the same..??

Comment: you may set drawables on left, top, right and bottom of the view. Moreover you may define the gap between drawable and the button/text by setting your button's/text's `setCompoundDrawablePadding(integer_padding)`

Comment: i am gettin a problem in here.. as i am generating layout programatically setCompoundDrawable is working fine when i am creating button and putting on Image inside.. but i have no idea how to use it inside onCLick() as i want to change the image again when the button is clicked...

Comment: create a boolean flag and toggle its value when a click event is occurred, for example: `isOn = !isOn;` and with in the same event write if/else statement to perform icon switching

Comment: you misunderstood..i am aware of programming to be done...u will not understand and poor me.. don't know how to put code in here

Comment: Button b2;
oncreate(-----)
{
               if (rowId == 51){
                        Drawable d1 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.radio1);
   d1.setBounds(0, 0, d1.getIntrinsicHeight(), d1.getIntrinsicWidth());
          Button b2 = new Button(getApplication());
   b2.setId(20);
   b2.setText("Major Scale");
   b2.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
   b2.setOnClickListener(this);
   b2.setCompoundDrawables(d1, null, null, null);
   Inner1.addView(b2, lpinner);
                   holder.addView(l2, tlp);
   outside.addView(holder, tlp);
   setContentView(outside);
  }

Comment: @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
                int id = v.getId();
            else if (id == 20) {
   Drawable d1 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.radio2);
   d1.setBounds(0, 0, d1.getIntrinsicHeight(), d1.getIntrinsicWidth());
   b2.setCompoundDrawables(d1, null, null, null);
  }
}

Comment: its hard to get hold. perhaps add a new question, put your code in that and paste the link here to notify me :)